# Need help with untar command - want to untar from multiple .tar files and then move files to common directory

Tags: command-line, tar

I have several tar files (~270) which untar into the following separate directory structure:

00001.tar -> /00001/001/file1.ima

00002.tar -> /00002/001/file2.ima

.
.
.

00270.tar -> /00270/001/file270.ima

I wondered if there is a specifier in the untar command that would allow me to not only untar the files, but also move the files (file1.ima, file2.ima, . . . file217.ima) to a common directory.

Does anyone know how to do this? Sorry if this is a simple thing to do; I am pretty inexperienced in this (obviously).

Thanks hugely in advance for any help on this!

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
for f in {00001..00270}.tar; do
  tar xf "$f" --strip-components=1 
done
```

should untar them all into directory `001` (i.e. stripping the leading path components `00001/`, `00002/` etc). If you want to untar them to a completely different location, you can use the `-C` option and (optionally) strip *both* original path components

```
for f in {00001..00270}.tar; do
  tar xf "$f" --strip-components=2 -C path/to/other/dir 
done
```

(directory `path/to/other/dir` must already exist).